# How to Mirror a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Part of my application requires it to be compatible if somebody was looking at the screen via mirror. Does anybody know a way where I can mirror all of the text on screen? I have tried `mirrorText.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);` but it hasn't worked. Thank you

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398283/android-mirroring-a-view

Comment: Uh God I'm going to have to do this for every single `textView` and `Button` aren't I. Can I apply this same method to the layout as a whole?

Comment: @user154248 - well, you could create a subclass of textview, maybe call it mirrorview, then write a method that mirrors it and derive all your textviews from mirrorview, if that helps. anyways, +1 for self-answering.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is very simple to accomplish. The code I used was: 

`Text.setScaleX(-1);
 Text.setScaleY(1);
 Text.setTranslationX(1); //To place everything back where it was originally.`
Hope this helps!

Comment: is the same logic would work with `SurfaceView` ? I need to mirror a video displayed by `SurfaceView`. tried rotation and `setScale` with no luck!

Comment: Not sure @Sam, this was posted back in 2016, different World now! Make sure you are doing a translation, not rotation.