# Android Camera:Front-camera mirror images

Tags: android, camera

How to make the front camera NOT be a mirror image ? I can't find the interface about how to mirror the image.

I am using the Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925278/drawing-mirrored-bitmaps-in-android) that describes how to mirror, it uses a matrix to flip it.  However, I'd try it out on a variety of devices first-  I hadn't heard that about the front camera and would be surprised if it wasn't a device specific thing.