# Why does the image byte data in onPictureTaken result in a mirrored image?

Tags: android

I call `takePicture` with a callback for the jpeg event: `camera.takePicture(null, null, this);`

Here is the callback handler:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), picture, "name" , "description");
}
```

In testing, I'm finding that the image is always mirrored about the y-axis. Does anyone know (1) whether this happens on for all devices, and (2) *why*? I really don't understand why the byte data doesn't represent what I see in the camera preview. Is that an unreasonable expection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using Front Camera right?
That is the behavior of Front Camera.
Even if you use a web cam on your laptop, it is the same.

If you want to fix it. Please refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925903/1198897)

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Is there documentation on whether the front camera *has* to mirror like that? Or is that an unwritten rule that all manufacturers follow?

Comment: I think it is a common spec. When the camera is facing you, it will take image from its perspective. (which is the opposite from what you see.) Not sure about documentation, but my Samsung, HTC, Sony devices all behavior this way.