# Why does ExtractMpegFramesTest not work with rotated input files?

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediacodec

I'm starting to decode/encode videos for an app and it seems that [BigFlake's site](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) is the authoritative reference for working video code. I've copied the [ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt) into my project and modified it to use different file paths, but nothing else. It extracts properly frames from pre recorded videos I copy into the device. However, when trying to use it with a video recorded from the device's camera I get frames which are just horizontal lines:

[image]

After testing different recorded videos I realised the problem comes from rotated videos. The device's camera encodes frames as they come from the framebuffer and then slaps a rotation tag on the video. This can be extracted from the `MediaFormat` object:

```
int rotation = format.getInteger("rotation-degrees");
```

Unfortunately swapping the width/height of the saved image doesn't alter anything, the images still get corrupted. What has to be done to the save code to handle rotated frames correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted by the [source code comment pointed out by another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862043/172690), OpenGL requires transforming the image. The original `invert` boolean helps with sources which have not been rotated or have a rotation of 180 degrees. But the other orientations (90 and 270) will display a flipped image, so they have to be flipped too.

Here are the changes I did to handle rotation correctly:

1. Read the `rotation-degrees` attribute (when available) from the source media.
2. Modify the `CodecOutputSurface` constructor to accept a numerical rotation parameter, which is stored in the `mRotation` instance variable.
3. Modify the original `invert` code to be used when the rotation is 0 or 180.
4. Use a different matrix transformation when the rotation is 90 or 270.

You can get the full modified version from [the following gist](https://gist.github.com/gradha/081b9c479a1539bda8ad8173ef593a04) as well as take a look at the [individual changes](https://gist.github.com/gradha/081b9c479a1539bda8ad8173ef593a04/revisions?diff=split) mentioned above.